# How to decrease CPU Usage when it reaches to 100% when using while(1) loop

Tags: c, windows, winapi, visual-studio-2008, while-loop

I am working on UDP Server/Multiple Client Application.

There are multiple threads handling multiple clients.

There is one single thread which keeps on sending KEEPALIVE Messages to each active clients. Since this thread is in `while(1)` so CPU Usage reaches to 100%.

Since I want this functionality to go on, I have used a `while(1)` thread. I also tried adding a `sleep` after each execution of `while` but I don't think `sleep()` frees the CPU. Is there any way I can decrease CPU Usage for a specific time. e.g after a single execution of while, I can free up the CPU for like 10 secs and then continue back to `while`.

Please help me. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `sleep()` does store context+abandons CPU to spare resources, a way to decrease CPU usage would be to limit the number of threads, best way would be keeping a waiting list before executing

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help :)

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sleep` - Suspends the execution of the current thread until the time-out interval elapses.
And gives processor to other threads which are ready to run.

source : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So, just `sleep` does it all you need.

Answer (score 3):

Sending keep-alive messages inside `while(1)` loop is bad idea because not only you burn all the CPU time but you also flood the network and storm the recipients of those messages. You can use `Sleep()` WinAPI function with a reasonable delay (10 seconds you suggested look reasonable) to suspend your sending thread for a while:

```
while( 1 ) {
   sendKeepAlive();
   Sleep( 10 * 1000 ); // 10 seconds
}
```

`Sleep()` definitely does suspend your thread and while the thread is suspended it doesn't consume CPU time.

Answer (score 1):

instead of sleep try `int usleep(useconds_t usec);`

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/usleep.html

For windows specific you can give a try to timeBeginPeriod / timeEndPeriod.See the link – http://www.geisswerks.com/ryan/FAQS/timing.html

Comment: Is that available on Windows too?

Comment: Yes, on windows there is a `Sleep(milliseconds)` function (in windows.h).

Comment: @RogerRowland yes you are right, there is no usleep in windows, but for windows specific one can brows this link http://www.geisswerks.com/ryan/FAQS/timing.html

Comment: I thought so - it's just that the OP tagged with Windows.

Comment: @RogerRowland i have edited my answer as per your suggestion.Hope it will help OP

Answer (score 0):

On Linux I use nanosleep() and then sleep(): `nanosleep(&tsleep,NULL);` `sleep(1500)`

```
    int period=100000;
    int limit=300;

    struct timespec twork,tsleep; //time to work, and time to sleep
    twork.tv_sec=0;
    twork.tv_nsec=period*limit*1000;
    tsleep.tv_sec=0;
    tsleep.tv_nsec=period*limit*1000;
```